# Ctrl +; no longer works after updating to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

Before the update, pressing Ctrl +; on Google Spreadsheet or Libreoffice displayed the date.
Currently, the underlined e is displayed.
Does anyone know how to fix it so that the date is displayed?

[Underlined e is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5vpi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch the tool "ibus-setup". On the tab "Emoji", disable - or change - the keyboard shortcut for Emoji annotation.

Comment: Thank vanadium. I was able to fix the problem by disabling emoji in ibus-setup.

Answer (score 0):

The correct shortcuts for both `LO Calc` and `Google Sheets` is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to insert the time

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to insert the date

In both cases, it's the colon key that is pressed.

It may be necessary to format the cell appropriately.

This was tried in both cases on a fresh instance of 22.04 LTS

[image]

Comment: I tried this,but the situation didn't change.