# What is the functionality of CTRL + .?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04

The keybinding to enter super-script text in gdocs is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

However, when pressing this on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, and GNOME 42.2, it inserts an underlined e, which then locks the backspace key from working, but allows characters to be typed. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> removes the underlined "e", and the text inserted after it, but pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> just removes the e.

Obviously with the way search engines process text input this is quite hard to search for and find an answer.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this, I just tried that on my instance of 22.04.01 with `Google Docs` using `Firefox` (apt version) and it produced super-script text perfectly as it does in v20.04. [edit] your question with further details of how your keyboard is configured in 22.04 and how you are using `Docs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hah, I tried that combination on my Jammy Jellyfish instance and this is what I see when I press the spacebar after the combination:

[image]

[image]

It brings up the **emoji choice menu**, and that's cool for me!

Comment: yep, after pressing space that comes up for me too - though there is still the issue that I can't write superscript text without going through the menus

Comment: You can search for emojis too by doing `CTRL` + `.`, then for example typing "joy", `SPACE`, then to accept, `ENTER`, which should give: .

Answer (score 3):

Launch the tool "ibus-setup". On the tab "Emoji", disable - or change - the keyboard shortcut for Emoji annotation.

Source: [Ctrl +; no longer works after updating to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413515/ctrl-no-longer-works-after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04)